# Using Native JavaScript, change the title attribute of an object if it has a certain CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

So by using native javascript, how would I go about saying
"if this object has this css class, add this to the title attribute"

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    if(element.classlist.contains("current_page_item")||element.classlist.contains("current-page-ancestor")){

    }
});
```

That is as far as I've gotten, I'm trying to stick to native javascript just so we don't have to load up any libraries and can keep the site as minimalist as possible.

Comment: `element.title+=" some more content"`

Comment: I'm always bad at asking questions... so I can do that part and have. But element is not defined. So how do I tell it what elements to check? Ideally I guess this would just be links, or just the links in the div with class "menu-primary-menu-container"

Answer (score 1):

You can use getElementsByClassName()

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("current_page_item");
```

Then loop and add title

```
x.forEach(function(element){
   element.title = "title";
});
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].title ="title";
}
```

To answer to your comment, to apply the title to the "a" element that is a child of the div element that has the "current_page_item" class

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    y[0].title = "title";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it says x.forEach is not a function

Comment: constantly adding scope.... so other than forEach saying it is not a function. How do I apply the title to the "a" element that is a child of the div element that has the "current_page_item" class?

Comment: var y = x[0].getElementsByTagName('a'); Then y[0].title = "title"

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rohit Shetty's reply, you could also use the querySelector:

```
let elements = document.querySelector(".current_page_item");
elements.forEach(function(e) {
  e.title = "title";
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByClassName()

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("current_page_item");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].title += "BLAH";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if I have understood well.

But let's try.
First, locate the elements.

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.current_page_item, .current_page_item')
// nodes are the elements of one of the classes names
```

Then, apply the class Names to title.

```
function containsOfTheClasses (node) {
    return classNames.some(x => node.classList.contains(x))
}

nodes.forEach(function (node) {
    node.title += classNames.filter(containsOfTheClasses).join(' ')
})
```